# Need a menu on left sidebar of the page with below requirements

Tags: menus

i have used below code to create Menu on left side of page.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left" id="nav">
<ul>
<li id="light">
   Video
  <ul>
   <li>Video 1</li>
   <li>Video 2</li>
   <li>Video 3</li>
   <li> Video 4</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="photo">
Photograms
    <ul>
   <li>Photograms 1</li>
   <li>Photograms 2</li>
   <li>Photograms 3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="about">
About
   <ul>
   <li>About 1</li>
   <li>About 2</li>
   <li>About 3</li>
   <li>About 4</li>
   <li>About 5</li>     
  </ul>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav ul ul{
  display: none;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#nav ul li')
.css({cursor: "pointer"})
.on('click', function(){
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
})
```

For this code i am getting like this..
[Menu Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn6lD.png)

But I want arrow mark for Video, photograms and about on clicking that arrow on clicking that arrow video1,video2,video3,video4 should be visible and when that arrow is not clicked these should be invisible.

Thanks,
Bhargav.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tutorial made for wordpress linke this one -> http://mysitemyway.com/docs/Collapsible_sidebar_menus

and use a jQuery for animation

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('.menu .dropdown a').click(function(e){  
          e.preventDefault();
          if (jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').is(':visible')) {
               jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').hide();
          } else {
               jQuery(this).parent().children('.sub-menu:first').show();
          }
     });
});
```